# deny access to directory but allow to sub directories, how?

Tags: image, .htaccess

Im using native EE image manipulations to create small images. How ever, EE saves the original files, and everyone can access to those.

I need to deny access to these original images but allow access to sub directories EE is created.

So, simple example:
/myimages/_cropped/image.jpg and
/myimages/_customsmall/image.jpg

Those are the files that I need to serve to visitors.

But I want to deny access to original images that are saved to
/myimages/image.jpg

How this can be done with something like via htaccess?
I've tried to google but did'nt find any articles about this.
I do not wat to use any password protection, but deny from all (the main directory) and yet to allow needed sub directories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peasy. Use .htaccess rules.

For /myimages/.htaccess:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

for /myimages/whateverdirectory/.htaccess:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: Thanks. Few first refreshes did show no-go but force refresh and works. Ah, good! :)